# Making an alias to add key to remote authorized_keys file

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, alias

Generally when creating a new web server, in order to login via SSH without having to type in a password, I would add the host to my `~/.ssh/config` file like so:

```
Host foobar
    HostName 111.111.111.111
    User myusername
```

Then I would run this command to copy my SSH key to the server.

`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh foobar "mkdir ~/.ssh; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

Is there a way I can make an alias in my .bash_profile/.bashrc to allow me to type something like `copy_key foobar` and it would copy my key to the server? I tried making a function in my .bashrc file with that long command but it just tried to login to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "alias" is bash script and it is called `ssh-copy-id`. Check manual pages: `man`[`ssh-copy-id`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id):

> **ssh-copy-id** is a script that uses ssh to log into a remote machine (presumably using a login password, so password authentication should be enabled, unless you've done some clever use of multiple identities) It also changes the permissions of the remote user's home, `~/.ssh`, and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to remove group writability (which would otherwise prevent you from logging in, if the remote `sshd` has `StrictModes` set in its configuration).